# Export a 3d plot from Octave to be shown interactively on a web browser

Tags: charts, octave, interactive

I would like to export a 3d plot done using Octave and to show it interactively using a web browser.

I would be able to rotate the plot as if I was seeing it directly using Octave.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried to search a bit but I have not found anything useful.
I found something for R here [R: using rgl to generate 3d rotatable plots that can be viewed in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663982/r-using-rgl-to-generate-3d-rotatable-plots-that-can-be-viewed-in-a-web-browser/) but I don't know how to do this in Octave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Octave itself creates 3d charts, but they are not interactive:**

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plotting.html

So you'll have to use another application and have octave feed data into 3d interactive charting software so that users can play with it on a webpage.

**"Processing" tool for 3d interactive charting**

software from (http://www.processing.org/) could help you.  You will be responsible for exporting the raw data from octave into the format acceptable for the interactive 3d plots.

**webMathematica 3.2 tool for 3d interactive charting**

software from (http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/examples/examples.html) that you can embed into your web page that can generate interactive and dynamic 2d and 3d content for users to play with.